# jQuery Select Hidden Input Value next toButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-selectors

I have a list of items. I want to be able to click a button to add item to mySQL. While testing I just have  conf box to show ID. Trouble is I can't get it to work. I am new to jQuery and AJAX. I think this is easy. But after a morning of trying a bunch of different methods from here without luck, I thought I would ask about my exact code.

```
<page loaded with>
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete');

<script>
function addCharItem () {
    var itemID = $(this).closest("td").find('input[name="itemID"]').val(); //this is close (I think) but message is showing as undefined.
//  var itemID = $("input").siblings(".itemID").val() //gets first ID in table only
    confirm ('The item ID is ' + itemID); 
//adding ajax and other stuff later.  
}
</script>

<html>
...
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"><dl><dt>Backpack (empty)</dt><dd></dd></dl></td>
  <td><input name="hdnItemID" type="hidden" value="742"/>
      <input name="btnAddItem" type="button" id="btnAddItem" value="+" onclick="addCharItem ()"/></td>
  <td><input name="btnBuyItem" type="button" id="btnBuyItem" value="$" /></td>
 </tr>
 ...
</html>
```

This is all built from a template php page in Wordpress. I don't think there is any weirdness with these things. But if there is let me know what else you may need. Thank you for all of your help and suggestions. I know I must be missing something small I just don't know this good enough yet to know what.

Comment: So far no luck. I added the following:  var thisValue = $(this);console.log(thisValue); to see what this was selecting. It returns this in the console:[Window, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]
  Shouldn't it have a selector? It is showing "". Maybe that is the problem. Why isn't 'this' grabbing the current element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems for some reason the above code was not grabbing the HTML element. So instead I implemented jQuery buttons.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var thisValue = $(this).val(); //to distinguish buttons
        console.log(thisValue);
        var itemID = $(this).prev('input[id="hdnItemID"]').val()
        confirm ('The item ID is ' + itemID);
            //do other stuff
      });
  });
</script>

<html changes>
...
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"><dl><dt>Backpack (empty)</dt><dd></dd></dl></td>
  <td><input class="itemID" id="hdnItemID" type="hidden" value="742"/>
    <input type="submit" value="+" /></td>
  <td><input class="itemID" id="hdnItemID" type="hidden" value="742"/>
    <input type="submit" value="$" /></td></tr>
...
</html>
```

I wish I could tell you why it wasn't working. It appears that I had tried many different ways that should have worked. The suggestions above should have worked too. If anyone knows why this is the case please let me know. I, and I am sure there are others, that would love to know this "gotcha" issue. Thanks for the tips all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.siblings(selector)`

```
 $(this).siblings('input[name="hdnItemID"]').val()
```

or

```
 $(this).prev('input[name="hdnItemID"]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `hdnItemID` as your name, not `itemID`

```
$(this).closest("td").find('input[name="hdnItemID"]').val();
```